# Create variable over ssh in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

```
#!/bin/bash -x

ssh -T root@jumpbox ssh -T root@IP << EOF  
YY=$(date +'%y')  
echo $YY  
EOF
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Trying tunnel from jumpbox...  
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.  
-bash: line 6: YY: command not found
```

The variable I need to assign is more complex, it's not about year number as shown in my description.

Comment: Firstly you can't have spaces around the  '=' in bash variable assignments. Secondly the output doesn't match the snippet. Thirdly -T actively suppresses terminal allocation, it doesn't mean  "tunnel" if that's what you're hoping for. All up this is a very poorly written question. How about you tell us what you're actually trying to achieve and post a self-contained coherent test case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you don't quote the `EOF` in `<<EOF`, expansions are perfomed by the local shell inside the here document (so the `$(date ...)` is expanded by the local `date` and `$YY` is expanded to the value in the local shell (empty unless you have assigned a value earlier)). If you the content of the here-document to be passed verbatim to the remote shell, you need to quote the `EOF` one way or another:

```
ssh -T root@IP << 'EOF'
YY=$(date +'%y')
echo "$YY"
EOF
```